# How to check if logged in user session is valid in Android Parse SDK?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently trying to setup user login and registration in my app. The first thing I am doing though is having my `MainActivity` check to see if a user is logged in and if they are, check if the session is valid. I am not sure if I am getting the `ParseSession` correctly, and if I am, I am not sure what to do at this point. (The docs are not very clear at showing how to accomplish this). Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ParseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.parse_app_id))
            .clientKey(getResources().getString(R.string.parse_client_key))
            .server(getResources().getString(R.string.parse_server_url))
            .build()
        );

        if (isFirstLaunch()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This is the first launch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (!isUserLoggedIn()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User is not logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isFirstLaunch() {
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
        currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            ParseSession.getCurrentSessionInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseSession>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseSession object, ParseException e) {
                    /*
                     * if session is valid
                     * return true
                     * if session is invalid
                     * run ParseUser.logOut()
                     * return false
                     */
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Session` are automatically managed by `ParseSession` these objects are stored on Parse in the Session class, and you can view them on the **Parse.com** Data Browser

More information on `Session` :Sessions represent an instance of a user logged into a device. Sessions are automatically created when users log in or sign up. They are automatically deleted when users log out.

There is one distinct Session object for each user-installation pair; if a user issues a login request from a device they’re already logged into, that user’s previous Session object for that Installation is automatically deleted.

[Reference of Site for more detail on Session class.](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#session-properties)

> How to check if logged in user session is valid in Android Parse SDK?

As mentioned above if user is valid (you can check it by `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()!= null`) and authenticated using `isAuthenticated()` method of `ParseUser` class. Session must be valid by default (Automatically managed by `ParseSession`). *And the way you checked for Session is correct but there is no need to check for valid session if user is valid and authenticated.*

Hope this is Helpful.

Comment: Hi @Dipali, I was looking at the docs and it says this for `isAuthenticated()`: `Whether the ParseUser has been authenticated on this device. This will be true if the ParseUser was obtained via a logIn or signUp method. Only an authenticated ParseUser can be saved (with altered attributes) and deleted.` I think this simply makes sure the user was logged in via registration or login at the time that he/she is logging in. I tried this and even though I deleted the session from the database, it still shows the user as logged in.

Comment: I tried this method and it seems to work but I don't know if it is recommended this way: https://gist.github.com/alexiz10/f93d2deca7cf4c83fbdef5f606a020c1

Comment: @AlexizHernandez, yes I've mentioned it already that it's fine using in this way. What I tried to indicate is why you want to check session validation if user is valid..

Comment: what I meant is that with `isAuthenticated()`, if I go to database on my end, and delete the user's session, the app will still keep the user as logged in.

Comment: 1. delete the session entry from database and kill the app. 2. delete the entry and don't kill app but try to do some operation with user. Now check is parse creating new entry how that manages..!! As sessions are managed by itself they must handle this scenarios.

Comment: Ah I think I get what you mean now. I will go ahead and do it that way then! Thanks!